# angular datatable data not binding properly from the API

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-datatables

am using angular datatable am getting data from api but table is not binding properly here is my code below

**App.component.html**

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Body</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ post.body }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**App.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CovidApiService} from '../../services/covid-api.service';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  posts;

  constructor(private covidApiService: CovidApiService, private http: HttpClient) {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 5,
      processing: true
    };

    this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .subscribe(posts => {
        this.posts = posts;
      });
  }

}
```

even though the table has data its shows no data available

here is my screenshot

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOTnY.png)

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: no errors @TheHeadRush

Answer (score 1):

As per angular datatable [doc](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way) you have to manually trigger the rendering of the table using `dtTrigger`

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Body</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <td>{{ post.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ post.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ post.body }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

in `.ts` file add dtTrigger

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CovidApiService} from '../../services/covid-api.service';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  posts;

   //use this trigger because fetching the list of posts can be quite long,
  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>(); 
  
  constructor(private covidApiService: CovidApiService, private http: HttpClient) {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 5,
      processing: true
    };

    this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .subscribe(posts => {
        this.posts = posts;
        // Calling the DT trigger to manually render the table
        this.dtTrigger.next();

      });
  }

}
```

and Do not forget to unsubscribe the event

Comment: In Angular 12 `this.dtTrigger.next()` is now `this.dtTrigger.next` while in HTML `[dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"` can be written to `dtOptions="dtOptions" dtTrigger="dtTrigger"`